# Is redis data stored as sds or as objects?

Tags: database, dictionary, redis, storage

I'm trying to understand the internals of Redis. It uses a simple implementation of a dictionary as data-storage in memory. Moreover data transferred from the client to the server is serialized by its own [RESP](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) protocol.

What I didn't figure out so far is how the data is stored in redis. Does it store the according RESP value as [simple dynamic string](https://redis.io/topics/internals-sds) (sds) or does it first parse the value from the RESP eg. as an integer and stores it as an int (possibly from the shared integers array), which then is a sds again? I'm getting curious since in dict.c e.g. `int dictAdd(dict *d, void *key, void *val){...}` data is used as void *, which could indicate that data is stored as string, int or anything else, but tracing it down I didn't find any piece of code converting sds into objects.

But if it stores the data as sds, how does it store lists and sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each data type in Redis has its own encoding, and most of them have several encodings for different scenarios. Even sds strings (and yes, string keys are usually sds strings) can have multiple encodings.

Sets, sorted sets, lists and hashes use a compact "ziplist" encoding in memory when they are small, but move to a memory wasteful yet faster encoding when they grow.

The most complex object is the sorted set, which is a combination of a skiplist and a hash table. And the new streams object also has a very interesting representation.

In RDB though, they get serialized into a compact representation and not kept as they are in memory.

Comment: Thank you, didn't find the responsible code at first. If anybody also stumbles upon this question, I recommend reading [redislabs:core-concepts](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-1-the-ziplist-representation/). This really helped me out there.